# how to load & render part of data when user click on certain page

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt, fst

I am facing an out-of-memory issue in R, when I tried to load multiple tables and render using [DT](https://github.com/rstudio/DT) in shiny.

I am wondering if it is possible to only provide table structure (eg, no of rows & column names) to DT, and pre-load first N rows data to display in the app, then load another N rows when user click another page (pagination enabled). I found DT has a `dataTableAjax` function that return a Ajax URL and can be queried by DT (not sure how it done)

The original datatables JS library has an similar feature (if I not mistaken), as in https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

For example,

```
sample_table <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1e7), b = rnorm(1e7), c = rnorm(1e7))

library(fst)

# write large data on disk
write_fst(sample_table, "sample_table.fst")

# how to load data on disk on-demand using Ajax?
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Server-side processing of DataTables',
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # create a widget using an Ajax URL created above
    tbl_ajax_url <- reactiveVal({
      dataTableAjax(
        session, 
        read_fst("sample_table.fst", from = 1, to = 100, as.data.table = TRUE), 
        outputId = 'tbl')
    })
    observeEvent(input$tbl_rows_current, {
      rows <- input$tbl_rows_current
      tbl_ajax_url(dataTableAjax(
        session, 
        # random access like fst, only load required data when user click the page
        read_fst("sample_table.fst", from = min(rows), to = max(rows), 
                 as.data.table = TRUE), 
        outputId = 'tbl'))
    })

    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data.table(
        a = numeric(), b = numeric(), c = numeric(),
        check.names = FALSE), rownames = FALSE, options = list(
          ajax = list(
            serverSide = TRUE, processing = TRUE,
            # not sure how to do this part, where url only return part of data
            url = tbl_ajax_url()
          )
        ))
    })
  }
)
```

If you have any other suggestions, please let me know as well. My primary objective is to **prevent loading all tables in R at once**, instead only load partially on-demand.

PS: I am not familiar with any HTML, CSS & JS, please be patient and provide as many details as possible, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out a solution by myself, but I just put here in case somebody interested.

Using `funcFilter` in `renderDT`, we can create a new data source and render to DT. I created a on-disk data source, which only read data saved on disk when needed using [fst](https://github.com/fstpackage/fst).

Code:

```
sample_table <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1e7), b = rnorm(1e7), c = rnorm(1e7))

library(fst)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

# write large data on disk
write_fst(sample_table, "sample_table.fst")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Server-side processing of DataTables',
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(data.frame(
        a = numeric(), b = numeric(), c = numeric(),
        check.names = FALSE), rownames = FALSE)
    }, funcFilter = dataTablesFilterOnDisk)
  }
)

dataTablesFilterOnDisk <- function(data, params) {
  start <- as.integer(params$start)
  length <- as.integer(params$length)
  total_rows <- fst::metadata_fst("sample_table.fst")$nrOfRows
  cleanDataFrame <- function(x, escape = params$escape) {
    if (escape != "false") {
      k = seq_len(ncol(x))
      if (escape != "true") {
        k = k[as.integer(strsplit(escape, ",")[[1]])]
      }
      for (j in k) if (is.character(x[, j]) || is.factor(x[, j])) 
        x[, j] = htmltools::htmlEscape(x[, j])
    }
    x = unname(x)  # remove column names
    if (!is.data.frame(x)) return(x)
    for (j in seq_len(ncol(x))) {
      xj = x[, j]
      xj = unname(xj)  # remove names
      dim(xj) = NULL  # drop dimensions
      if (is.table(xj)) xj = c(xj)  # drop the table class
      x[[j]] = xj
    }
    unname(x)
  }
  row_range <- c(start + 1L, start + length)

  data <- fst::read_fst("sample_table.fst", columns = colnames(data), 
                        from = row_range[1L], 
                        to = min(row_range[2L], total_rows))
  
  list(draw = as.integer(params$draw), recordsTotal = total_rows, 
       recordsFiltered = total_rows, data = cleanDataFrame(data), 
       DT_rows_all = NULL, 
       DT_rows_current = seq.int(row_range[1L], row_range[2L], by = 1L))
}
```

See more references:

1. https://github.com/grahamrp/dtdatasources